# Randomly Transforming Everything in ImageDataGenerator at Once in tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence to model.fit_generator.
I'm retrieving data and shuffling one batch at a time instead of loading everything into ram.
In my `__init__`, I have `self.datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2)`.
Then in my `__getitem__`, I have:

```py
self.datagen.fit(x_batch)
x_batch = next(self.datagen.flow(x_batch, batch_size=len(x_batch)))
```

Is this the best way to transform everything at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could just call `fit_generator` instead of `fit` and `next`. In this way, you wouldn't need to iterate over all your data. For more information about `fit_generator` take a look into [keras help](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator)

Comment: That's what I wrote though. I'm already using fit_generator with custom sequence class. I'm generating custom batch in my sequence class, and I was wondering what's the best way to transform the entire batch with ImageDataGenerator for augmentation.

Comment: Forgive me if I understand wrong, but you wrote that you was using `fit` which is different of `fit_generator`. You just want do augment you data and save in disk or you want to augment your data and train with it?

Comment: No problem. I wrote "I'm using tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence to model.fit_generator." I want to augment images to train. Regardless, my question is about what's the best way to transform number of images at once, not how to feed them to model.

Comment: You don't have many alternatives. As far as a know, with Keras, or you load them at once into the memory and apply the augmentation or you do like you are doing applying the augmentation to batches of data. The best way will depend on what you are defining the best to your scenario, e.g., speed or low memory consumption...